# Reverse proxy in Azure with Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm moving from Apache on Linux to Azure Web Apps and I have a specific url (mysite.com/blog and everything under it) that is configured with a reverse proxy so the end user doesn't know that the content is actually coming from another service.

I'm sure I can do this within Web Apps (which runs on IIS) but I can't find any documentation on how to do this. As a backup I'm open to putting another service in front of my Web App.

How can I accomplish this in Azure?

Update: I did try using another service - Functions. My architecture looks like this:[image]

This works in production but I'm hitting snags in development. `/blog` may or may not work depending on the entry point. In prod, our DNS will be configured so `mysite.com` points to `mysite-proxy.azurewebsites.net` and, therefore, any URI the user hits will work. In dev, however, we may want to browse to hit `/blog` from the Traffic Manager which will route us to `/blog` on the webapp which *doesn't exist*. Same problem, of course, if we go to `/blog` directly on the webapp. I tried to show these examples on the right side of the diagram.

I would like to find a solution so the webapp itself can handle the `/blog` proxying and then we can determine whether it's worth the speed and cost tradeoff compared to the existing solution.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to checkout Azure Functions Proxies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies

Comment: Yes Function Proxies are supported on top of Function Apps and not Web Apps. One option could be to have all the traffic go thru a Function App with Proxy and make a change on your WebApp to do a redirect to the proxy if the request did not come from Proxy. You could add a shared key header between Proxy and the WebApp and in the WebApp if the incoming  header is not present do a redirect. yes I understand you would need to make a code change on your web app for this to work.

Comment: Basically you should secure your WebApp backend using EasyAuth, shared header, ... so the requests to the WebApp only come from the proxy.

Comment: Also if your scenarios are not too complex, you may want to checkout IIS UrlRewrite:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

Comment: And more info here: http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/

Comment: @ Henry here's an even better resource for doing the reverse proxy in IIS: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zhiliang_xus_blog/2016/01/19/build-a-google-reverse-proxy-site-on-azure-web-app-in-less-than-3-minutes/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an Application Gateway (caution, costs like $15/day)

The AGW can have multiple listeners against multiple hostnames, including path-based routing.

You will want to add two backends, one for the /blog endpoint and one for the non-/blog stuff. The backends just take the IP or FQDN of the target resource, in this case you will have:

- blogBackend: myblog.com
- defaultBackend: myWebapp.azurewebsites.net

Then you need to add listeners for your public-facing domain, it would be like:

- myHttpListener: port 80, hostname=mywebsite.net
- myHttpsListener: port 443, hostname=mywebsite.net

Then you need an HTTP setting

- myHttpSetting: protocol=HTTPS, port=443, useWellKnownCACert=Yes, HostnameOverride=Yes,pick from backend target

Then you need rules, one for http=>https redirect, and the other for handling the pathing

- myRedirectRule: type=basic, listener=myHttpListener, backendtargettype=redirection, targettype=listener, target=myHttpsListener
- myRoutingRule: type=path-based, listener=myHttpsListener, targettype=backendpool, target=defaultBackend, httpSetting=myHttpSetting, pathRules=

  - path=/* name=root backendpool=defaultBackend
  - path=/blog name=blog backendpool=blogBackend

You can create additional http settings and assign them to the path rules to change the behaviour of the reverse proxy. For example, you can have the user's URL be https://mywebsite.net/blog, but have the path stripped on the request to the blog so the request looks like myblog.com instead of myblog.com/blog

There's a lot of tiny parts, but the app gateways can handle multiple applications at scale. Biggest thing is to watch out for the cost since this is more of an enterprise solution.